# Can we connect Sharepoint to SQL Server 6.5?

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint

Not able to import application definition file!! Error: The metadata object with Name 'XYZ' and of Type 'LobSystemInstance' has a Property with Name 'DatabaseAccessProvider' that has either an invalid value or Type. Error was encountered at or just before Line: '10' and Position: '10'.

line 10 in ADF:

```
 <"Property Name="DatabaseAccessProvider" Type="System.String">SqlOledb<"/Property>
```

Please give me ideas on how to display data from SQL Server 6.5 in Sharepoint?

Comment: 6.5!?  Really?  My condolences.

Comment: SharePoint is just an ASP.NET application. If you can do it in ASP.NET, you can in SharePoint.

Comment: Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

The value of the node is invalid. You need to use **SqlServer** or **OleDb**. Check out this page for more information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms550725(office.12).aspx

Comment: If I use OleDb, the ADF is successfully imported but when i try to use business data list web part it is giving me an error:"error occured while retrieving the data from XYZinstance"!! even I tried with application definition designer, it is connecting to the database but not able to create the lobsystem instance..After I drag n drop the table and click ok, its popping uo this mess: " desginer stopped working abruptly!!"

Answer (score 0):

Im just starting on a similar task (so I found your unanswered question). I am trying to copy our documentation library in Sharepoint to an SQL db. Its not opening your file directly from SQL its using some c# code to setup a job which opens the sharepoint which may be what you are wanting.

There are two methods I have found so far:
One is to copy your data from sharepoint to a linked list in Access and then use the OLEDB methods in to open it. 
 Found here: [C# Sync MS Access database to sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770684/c-sharp-sync-ms-access-database-to-sql-server)

```
    private static void BulkCopyAccessToSQLServer
            (CommandType commandType, string sql, string destinationTable)
    {
        string connectionString = @"C:\Migration\Sharepoint Access SQL Batch Job\Database11.accdb";
        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
        {

            string ConnStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Migration\Sharepoint Access SQL Batch Job\Database11.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=password";
            //using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(Settings.Default.CurriculumConnectionString))
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnStr))
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn))
            using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = commandType;
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 240;
                adapter.Fill(dt);
                adapter.Dispose();
            }



            using (SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection(Settings.Default.qlsdat_extensionsConnectionString))

            using (SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conn2.Open();
                using (SqlBulkCopy copy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn2))
                {
                    copy.DestinationTableName = destinationTable;
                    copy.BatchSize = 1000;
                    copy.BulkCopyTimeout = 240;
                    copy.WriteToServer(dt);
                    copy.NotifyAfter = 1000;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The other is to use the Microsoft.Sharepoint libraries and open your sharepoint directly from the c# then copy it into your SQL.
Found here: http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/3573-fetching-lists-from-sharepoint-2010-site.aspx

```
    using (SharePointclientObj.ClientContext ctx = new SharePointclientObj.ClientContext(clientContext))
        {                
            //Get the site
            SharePointclientObj.Web site = ctx.Web;
            ctx.Load(site);
            //Get Lists
            ctx.Load(site.Lists);
            //Query
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            //Fill List
            foreach (SharePointclientObj.List list in site.Lists)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(list.Title);                   
            }

        }
```

Comment: Doh! I just realized your question was going the other way. If this is useful I will leave it, if not then I can delete it. 

I think you can use the same libraries to go the other way, but switch the reads and writes. Maybe by writing your SQL to access and use access to be linked to your sharepoint. 

I haven't done this direction so I dont have any code handy, but that is a description of one method.

Before you do that try using the built in import tools to load the SQL into sharepoint directly or baring that load it into access then see if you can get the access into sharepoint.